# Cannot run drush rsync - PHP Fatal error in sitealias.inc

Tags: drush

drush rsync @ dev @stage

> PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in
>   /usr/local/share/drush/includes/sitealias.inc on line 1468

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable
Error:

> Unsupported operand types in
>   /usr/local/share/drush/includes/sitealias.inc, line 1468

Comment: I assume the space between @ dev is a typo here only?

Comment: Trying to use 'rsync' to sync file system of dev site to stage site. Getting PHP fatal error. sitealias.inc. When installed on Rackspace server attempting 'drush rsnc' or 'drush sql-sync' breaks drush. Tried installing with pear, composer and just uploading a drush.zip file from github.None seem to work. Drush 7.0.0.0 acts all wonky and spazzes out. Even initialized a CLEAN Apache/Linux server...nothing works, including "How to make drush work on ANY server: https://www.drupal.org/node/2132447

Comment: Thanks Ryan, yes, just a typo. Been beating this one up for a week...

Comment: Sorry, Patrick. ;)

Comment: Where have you defined your site aliases? In sitealias.inc? Do the basic `drush status` and `drush rq` commands work?

Comment: Run again with --debug and show output.  Show output of `drush sa @dev`, `drush sa @stage`, `drush @dev status`, and `drush @stage status`.

Comment: I defined three aliases and put them in etc/drush:

Comment: devyau.alias.drushrc.php, stageyau.alias.drushrc.php, and prodyau.alias.drushrc.php

Comment: drush status and drush rq both work - now that I corrected some errors in my alias files. Now drush DOESN'T break, and drush rsync (at)devyau (at)stageyau works.

Comment: However drush sql-sync (at)devyau (at)stageyau fails with this message: Starting to dump database on Source. Unable to load class Drupal\Driver\Database\\Drush [error]PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function dump() on a non-object in root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc on line 275Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.Error: Call to a member function dump() on a non-object in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc, line 275

Comment: drush sa @devayu gives: $aliases["devyau"] = array (
  'uri' => 'dev.youngamericansunited.org',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/dev.youngamericansunited.org/',
);

Comment: drush sa @stageyau gives: $aliases["stageyau"] = array (
  'uri' => 'stage.youngamericansunited.org',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/stage.youngamericansunited.org',
);

Comment: OH: drush @devyau status gives: Unable to load class Drupal\Driver\Database\\Drush
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function db_spec() on a non-object in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc on line 370
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
Error: Call to a member function db_spec() on a non-object in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc, line 370
[root@web01-new dev.youngamericansunited.org]#

Comment: and drush @stageyau status does the same: [root@web01-new dev.youngamericansunited.org]# drush (at)stageyau status
Unable to load class Drupal\Driver\Database\\Drush  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function db_spec() on a non-object in/root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc on line 370Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error                                      [error] Error: Call to a member function db_spec() on a non-object in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc, line 370
[root@web01-new dev.youngamericansunited.org]#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an error in my alias files. I had a space between SQL username and password.

```
$aliases['devyau'] = array(
  'uri'=> 'dev.[sitename]',
  'root'=> '/var/www/vhosts/dev.[sitename]/',
  'db-url' => 'mysql://[username]: [password]/devDBname',
);
```